# Limpeza de Dados - SQL Server

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Estou trabalhando com uma coluna de telefones, porém algumas linhas possuem dois telefones separados por ";".

```
99999999 ; 99999222
12345678 ; 87654321
40028922
123123456 ; 1122334455
```

O meu objetivo é colocar os telefones duplicados em outras linhas separadas.

```
99999999
99999222
12345678
87654321
40028922
123123456
1122334455
```

Teria alguma maneira de realizar isso com SQL?

Comment: Qual a versão do SQL Server??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se a versão do SQL Server é 2016 (ou mais recente), experimente:

```
-- código #1
SELECT E.ID, rtrim (ltrim (SS.[value])) as Telefone
  from dbo.tbEmpresa as E 
       cross apply String_Split (E.Telefones, ';') as SS;
```

Entretanto, se for anterior a 2016, eis outra solução:

```
-- código #2
SELECT E.ID, 
       ltrim (rtrim (SS.Item)) as Telefone
  from dbo.tbEmpresa as E 
       cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K (E.Telefones, ';') as SS;
```

O código da função de usuário DelimitedSplit8K, de autoria de Jeff Moden, está no final do artigo “[Separar conteúdo de texto multivalorado (string split)](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2019/01/27/separar-conteudo-de-texto-multivalorado_string-split/)”.

Comment: Excelente, funcionou!